# PHP- find which names in variable appear in page

Tags: php, arrays, string, match

I've spent countless days trying to figure this out... I have a list of names I want to check for on my page. How can I check for these in a string. The last thing I tried was `str_word_count`

```
$members = "anne, barb, max"
print_r(str_word_count($members, 1));
```

Obviously that just returns an array of the $members variable. I want to check for the variables in my file and return which names were found.

I know this is probably a super easy question but, as my username suggests, I am a SuperN00b.

Comment: Tipp: `strpos()` like `if(strpos('my funny text page','funny')!==false)echo 'funny found';`. But only to get it, you are trying to find `anne` or `barb` or `max` in the page/content? `str_word_count()` counts only the words in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**index.php**

```
$data = file_get_contents('page.php');

$names = ['simon', 'jeff'];

foreach($names as $name)
{
    if(strpos($data, $name))
    {
        echo $name . " Is in file! <br>";
    }
}
```

**page.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


anna barry simon puma george jessica michael
jamil adil john jeff


</body>
</html>
```

**Output of this specific code**

```
simon Is in file! 
jeff Is in file!
```

Is this along the lines of what you were looking for?

Comment: actually this works great for finding the data in the file. The information I really need is spit out using var_dump. (The data/names are scraped from another source.) Could you point me in the direction to find how to get contents from spit out info?

Comment: If its spit out you could assign that data to a variable instead of var_dumping, you could use a session variable which means you can use this data on any other page that starts a sessions -> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp